# How to change text color in cell of data grid

Tags: c#, winforms, datagrid

I can't find any examples of how to change text color in any cell of data grid. If anybody know how to do it please help me. I am using data grid in winform application and I want to gray out some text in specified cell.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Style.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightGray;
```

Edit:
In DataGrid you have to override Paint method. You probably found this by yourself: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winforms/thread/e1cdc083-cc1c-4ef4-b444-434c6b7cd225
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2214/Changing-the-background-color-of-cells-in-a-DataGr

Comment: I am using datagrid, not datagridview unfortunately.

Comment: Well, unfortunetly there is no easy way, you need to override "Paint" method. See here for more:  
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winforms/thread/e1cdc083-cc1c-4ef4-b444-434c6b7cd225

Comment: OK, I will try as soon as possible, and answer here. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

in the properties of datagrid view set default cell style forecolor to be what ever you like